# ORA-01843 not a valid month using OCI8 php

Tags: php, oracle, oci8, to-date

I have a `oci8` module installed with `PHP` and when using a `to_date` conversion in my query I get an error. When I use the exact same query in my sql developer it works just fine.

**php:**

```
include("db_connection.php");


$query = "select count(distinct mp_eic) kogus, asp
from tellitud_eic
where work_type in ('E63001','E90000')
and wo_issued_meter is not null
and to_date(actual_completion, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') < '01.01.2014'
group by asp";


$parseQuery = oci_parse($connection, $query);

$result = oci_execute($parseQuery);

$sqlResultJson = array();


while ($row = oci_fetch_array($parseQuery, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    array_push($sqlResultJson, $row);
}

$json = json_encode($sqlResultJson);

echo $json;
```

**error:**

```
Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\queries\query_2013_installation_by_asp.php on line 15
Warning:  oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\queries\query_2013_installation_by_asp.phpon line 
[]
```

I used one other query with a different to_date format and this one worked `(to_date(to_char(to_date(p_kuu, 'mm'), 'MONTH'), 'MONTH');)`
so I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: use TO_DATE('01.01.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') instead of literal constant. And google NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter please.

Comment: format mask is correct. I can see the value in actual_completion column like for example '20.08.2013 22:13:56'
and it works just fine when I execute it in sqlplus or sql developer.

Comment: ok got it now. I didn't understand your comment previously. now it's working thanks!

correct query:
select count(distinct mp_eic) kogus, asp
from tellitud_eic
where work_type in ('E63001','E90000')
and wo_issued_meter is not null
and to_date(actual_completion, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') <  to_date('01.01.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
group by asp